# Unmarshalling Error-Null in JAX-WS WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, ejb, unmarshalling

I'm new to Java EE and WebServices, implementing basic one with the help of some tutorial.
Everything was working fine when only getMovie, getMovieList function were there but then I tried
to add addMovie function and suddenly it started giving error, could you please help in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

> Movie.java

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {

        private long movieId;
        private String movieName;
        private int yearMovieRelease;
...
...Getters and Setters...
}
```

> MovieData.java

```
@Singleton 
@LocalBean
@Startup 
public class MovieData {
        
        private List<Movie> movies;
        
        @PostConstruct
        public void initial(){
                movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
                
                movies.add(new Movie(1,"Movie1",2015));
                movies.add(new Movie(2,"Movie2",2016));
                movies.add(new Movie(3,"Movie3",2017));
                movies.add(new Movie(4,"Movie4",2018));
                movies.add(new Movie(5,"Movie5",2019));
                
        }
        
        public Movie getMovie(int movieId){
                Movie findMovie=null;
                
                for(Movie movie : movies){
                        if(movie.getMovieId()==movieId){
                                findMovie=movie;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                
                return findMovie;
        }
        
        public String addMovie(Movie movie){
                movies.add(movie);
                return "Movie added Successfully";
        }
        
        public List<Movie> getMovieList(){
                return movies;
        }
}
```

> MovieServiceJAXWS.java

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean 
@WebService(serviceName = "MovieServiceJAXWS")
public class MovieServiceJAXWS { 
        
        @EJB MovieData movieData;
        
        @WebMethod
        public Movie getMovie(@WebParam(name="movieId") int movieId){
                return movieData.getMovie(movieId);
        }
        
        @WebMethod
        public List<Movie> getMovieList(){
                return movieData.getMovieList();
        }
        
        @WebMethod
        public String addMovie(Movie movie){                
                return movieData.addMovie(movie);
        }
}
```

> server stack trace

```
18:36:18,063 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-1) Interceptor for {http://soapj8test.tanmshar.com/}MovieServiceJAXWS#{http://soapj8test.tanmshar.com/}addMovie has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: null 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:932)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:738)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 10]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:881)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$200(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$3.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:920)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:918)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 10
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:744)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:771)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$Factory.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:415)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:699)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:577)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$Factory.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:411)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.tanmshar.soapj8test.Movie.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.tanmshar.soapj8test.MovieFactory.createMovie(MovieFactory.java)
    ... 81 more
```

> soap request xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soapj8test.tanmshar.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:addMovie>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <movieId>6</movieId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <movieName>Movie6</movieName>
            <yearMovierelease>2020</yearMovierelease>
         </arg0>
      </soap:addMovie>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> soap request output

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: null</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you add the code for MovieFactory class?

Comment: @RahulSingh Apologies, I guess I don't have any class named MovieFactory in my code  (at least I've not create any)

Comment: I see this in the logs : com.tanmshar.soapj8test.MovieFactory.createMovie(MovieFactory.java)

Comment: @RahulSingh do you think it can be like it is looking for MovieFactory in that package but couldn't find it? because my code doesn't have any MovieFactory (double checked it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made below changes in Movie.java

#1

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "movie")
```

#2

default constructor no arguments

```
        public Movie(){
        }
```

and then it started working...

Soap output

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:addMovieResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soapj8test.tanmshar.com/">
         <return>Movie added Successfully</return>
      </ns2:addMovieResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```